# Access Replace function erroring if field is empty

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that contains the following:

```
Field1: Replace([Field1],"ü",", ")
```

This works great if there is something in Field1. The data in Field1 usually looks like 1ü2, 0ü0, 1ü1, etc. However, if a record has nothing in Field1 I get the following error:

```
This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables.
```

If I change the field to `Field1: Field1` the query runs with no errors. Is there a way to deal with the possibility of Field1 being blank?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to deal with the possibility of `Field1` containing a `null` value.

The first parameter of the `Replace` function cannot contain a `null` value, so you use the `nz` function convert all `null` values to something else, in this case it will be `""`

```
Field1: Replace(nz([Field1],""),"ü",", ")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, my Access DB XML export was falling over whenever it hit a row with a null value - this fixed it for me! :)